# Why is my Python Lambda function timing out while trying a POST request?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, splunk, python-requests-html

I have a python script that makes a couple of HTTP requests, working 100% when I run it locally.
I need to implement this script in a lambda function in AWS.

Since I'm using ***requests*** to make the script work, I learned that the requests library had to be imported into the lambda function's repository, and I already did that.
In fact I have another lambda working similarly with a python script, making a GET request, working without any issues. **The problem is that this new script tries to make a POST request and for some reason it gets stuck in it, timing out every time I try to test it**.

I have increased the preset timeout time all the way to 60 seconds, and it still times out.

This is the part of the function where the timeout is happening:

```py
def getFilePaths(fileList):
    filePaths = []
    if fileList:
        print("fileList has values!")
        print(fileList)
        for file in fileList: # for each file name in the input list
            print("started with: " + file)
            filePath = ''
            searchURL = '{}/servicesNS/{}/search/search/jobs'.format(baseURL,un)
            print(searchURL)
            resp = requests.post(url=searchURL, data={'search': 'search ' + file}, verify=False, auth=(un, pw)) # create search job for current file
            print("search job requested!")
            if resp.ok:
                ...
```

When I run a test, I check the function logs and everything works fine, until it gets to the line where the post request is done.

`resp = requests.post(url=searchURL, data={'search': 'search ' + file}, verify=False, auth=(un, pw))`

I'm fairly new to AWS and I've found some articles mentioning that this may be caused by the lambda function being in a VPC, but this is not the case.
I'm not sure if the execution role that I'm using for it has something to do, but I have no access to create a new one. I've been just using one that was available (and it has worked fine with GET requests).

Another point to highlight is that this POST request is trying to run a search in a **Splunk server**.
I don't have access to viewing or modifying its settings, but if this may be caused by any configuration with it, I can try asking the administrator to adjust it. Although I personally believe the problem is somewhere else, since as I mentioned, running the exact same script locally works correctly.

***Does anyone know what could be causing my script to get stuck at this specific line, and only when I try to test it in AWS Lambda?***

***Thanks in advance for your help!***

Comment: Have you tried making the `requests.post` call locally?

Comment: @PeterStenger Yes! When I run the entire script locally, it works fine... (meaning I run the python script from the Windows command line).

Comment: Is the request timing out or does it just freeze? You could try setting the 'timeout' kwarg to N seconds in the request to ensure that you getting stuck in the specific request and debug from there.

Comment: @spencer.pinegar It is timing out, and I already tried increasing the timeout time to 60 seconds. When I run it locally though, it only takes 1-2 seconds to run completely, so it shouldn't require more than that.

Comment: @JorgeChávez Hopefully this find you well! I would recommend that you use a library called Backoff to automatically retry the falling request; https://github.com/litl/backoff - it is super easy to use because it just wraps the function in a decorator. You may not be able to fix the problem directly, but this might be a worthwhile workaround. Best of luck - problems like this aren't always the funnest but keep banging your head against your keyboard and youll get through it!

Comment: I would suggest you check 2 things: First, test the same lambda on a working URL that is always working, like google.com, etc. Second, on which port do you work? maybe you need to add permission to the lambda to make outbound calls on this port.